# break from each function of Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Please don't mark duplicate or give negative mark before reading it carefully.

Break from .each function of Mongodb cursor function after reading all documents &  continue for logic further. I know there is no break statement for each loop.

I am looping over each document in Mongodb & after finishing off i want to do my further logic. If i give 'return' statement it will take me out of function. i don't want to go out of function.

```
function update (){               
          var resultCursor = dbCollection.find();
           resultCursor.each(function(err, result) {
           if (result == null)
           {
            //// I want to break from here & continue to logic further
             //return false;

           };
           console.log('result  for each item is ',result);

           //Calculate distance for from location if < 1000 meters
            riderFromLat = reqBody.fromLoc.lat;
            riderFromLong = reqBody.fromLoc.lng;

          var fromDistance = geolib.getDistance({latitude: riderFromLat, longitude: riderFromLong }, {latitude: result.fromLoc.coordinates[0], longitude: result.fromLoc.coordinates[1]});

         console.log(' From Distance is ',fromDistance);
          if ( fromDistance < 1000 )
            {

          riderToLat = reqBody.toLoc.lat;
          riderToLong = reqBody.toLoc.lng;

             var toDistance = geolib.getDistance({latitude: riderToLat, longitude: riderToLong }, {latitude: result.toLoc.coordinates[0], longitude: result.toLoc.coordinates[1]});
              console.log(' To Distance is ',toDistance);

               if (toDistance <= 1000)
                {
                   jsonResultData.finalMatchDriverList.push(result);
                }
            }
         });


        // Want to continue with logic further here over jsonResultData
 console.log ('jsonResultData.finalMatchDriverList.length',jsonResultData.finalMatchDriverList.length );
}
```

Question  :- 
      I want to loop over each document & after looping i want to continue my code further. Hopefully there must be solution for this one. Need some guidance for that only.

Comment: Add a function that is called from within `update()` with the json result i.e `processResult(jsonResultData);`?

Comment: Intent is to get out of document after finishing all Mongodb reading database. Just amazed we don't have any simple solution for it.

Comment: use `Array#every` return false to "break"

Comment: @JaromandaX can you explain in bit more detail with example which fits in here. Question is still open.

Comment: Sorry, I find your code hard to understand, I based my comment on the `Break from .each` part of the question

Comment: What do you mean by "after looping i want to continue my code further"? Once your loop is done, your code does continue further. Inside the loop, if your function returns early, then the loop doesn't "break" (that word is used to mean that the loop stops before it has finished going over each item), it just goes on to the next item. Where are variables like `riderToLat` and `jsonResultData` being defined?

Comment: @PeterBehr see this code as an :-examplefunction update (){
     var jsonresults = [];
     var resultCursor = dbCollection.find();
       resultCursor.each(function(err, result) {
           if(result == null) {
                // Return will take me outside of update function. I don't want to do that. 
                return;
             }
           else  {
           // logic for work to be done on result. Do comparison & push data in some jsonresults array }
       )};
     // now after finishing off i want to continue over my update function whatever else is left.
}

Comment: In update function after going over all MongoDB document & finding what i need. i.e. results .  I want to do some work on results and further bushiness logic which i want to implement.

Comment: @RaviSingh It's possible that MongoDB `.each()` behaves like jQuery `.each()`, in that returning `false` in the function used to loop acts as a `break`, but returning any truthy value acts as a `continue`...I'm guessing on account of this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4826. Try `return true;` and see if that works.

Comment: @PeterBehr As expected  which seems logical to me. It didn't work. I tried return true & return false both. your guess doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: @RaviSingh in that case, more information about what output you actually are getting would be helpful. Is an exception being thrown? Also, which version of MongoDB you're using, and other setup details might help you and others debug. The code you show seems to have a lot of possible problems, and now reading the most recent documentation I see that the method to loop over cursors is `.forEach()`, not `.each()`, which takes a function that accepts only one variable (the current doc in the loop): <https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach>.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MongoDB and can't judge if there's a better way of doing it (and probably there is) but given your description this is possibly what you want:

```
function update (){
      var results = [];

      function  doThisAfterwards() {
        // you can access results here; 
      }

      var resultCursor = dbCollection.find();
       resultCursor.each(function(err, result) {
           if(result) {
                // do what you want
                results.push(result);
           }
           else  {
                doThisAfterwards();
           }
       );
}
```

Comment: Although your solution provides quick workaround which is good & much appreciated for that but it didn't provide me exact what i am looking for, so i am still letting question open to answer.